# Squeeze Theorem for Factorials

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

I have been having trouble with questions with factorials in Squeeze Theorem.

This is the questions that I am struggling with:

$\lim_{x\to \infty} {x^x\over(2x)!}$

What I have done so far:

Lower Limit = $0$ because the lowest value that the function can be is when $n=0$.

I tried to workout the upper limit as follows:

${x^x \over (2x)!} = {x \over 2x} \times {x \over (2x-1)} \times {x \over (2x-2)} ... \times {x \over (2x - (x-1))}$

$= {x^x \over (2x)!} = {x \over 2x} \times {x \over (2x-1)} \times {x \over (2x-2)} ... \times {x \over (x+1)}$

However, I don't know how to proceed from this point on. Any hints on tackling this problem would be much appreciated. Any tips on solving factorials with squeeze theorem in general would also be be helpful.

Comment: Should that be a limit as $x$ goes to infinity? Otherwise, what exactly do you mean by the factorial symbol?

Comment: I'm guessing they really want the limit as $x$ goes to positive infinity and is an integer. Otherwise, you have rather a mess involving the Gamma function; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: Yeah sorry it was supposed to be infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use $n$ instead of $x$. Note that if $n\ge 1$ then
$$\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}=\frac{1}{n!}\left (\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n}{n+2}\cdot\frac{n}{n+3}\cdots \frac{n}{2n}   \right).$$
But it is clear that 
$$\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n}{n+2}\cdot\frac{n}{n+3}\cdots \frac{n}{2n}  \lt 1.$$
Thus if $n\ge 1$ then 
$$0\lt \frac{n^n}{(2n)!}\lt \frac{1}{n!}.$$
As $n\to\infty$, the quantity $\frac{1}{n!}\to 0$. It follows by Squeezing that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}=0.$$

**Remark:** The question asked for a *general* procedure. That I cannot provide. There *are* recurring themes, and after doing a number of problems one gets accustomed to some of them.

Comment: You are welcome.